# Dealing With References to a Module When Module is Restricted With Count

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I am trying to enable/disable a module which includes a bunch of resources using count, see below:

```
module "rds_aurora_postgres" {  
  count = var.rds_aurora_postgres_enabled ? 1 : 0
  ... 
}
```

Sprinkled throughout the project there are references to the outputs of that module. Either I am doing something wrong, or the construct above will not emit the properties during the planning phase when count is used. Many, many errors such as the one below is returned when count is used.

> Error: Unsupported attribute
>
> on rds-aurora-staging.tf line 94, in resource
> "aws_security_group_rule" "ingress_dms_silver_aurora":   94:
> security_group_id =
> module.rds_aurora_postgres.primary_rds_server_security_group_id
> ├────────────────
> │ module.rds_aurora_postgres is a list of object
>
> Can't access attributes on a list of objects. Did you mean to access
> attribute "primary_rds_server_security_group_id" for a specific
> element of the list, or across all elements of the list?

```
resource "aws_security_group_rule" "ingress_dms_silver_aurora" {
  count = var.rds_aurora_postgres_enabled ? 1 : 0
  description       = "DMS Silver Ingress"
  type              = "ingress"
  from_port         = "5432"
  to_port           = "5432"
  protocol          = "tcp"
  source_security_group_id       = aws_security_group.dms_instance_silver.id
  # The line below causes error when module contains a count construct
  security_group_id = module.rds_aurora_postgres.primary_rds_server_security_group_id
}
```

The above errors do not occur when count is removed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using `count`, your module will output results as a list, so you need to fix it like this:

```
resource "aws_security_group_rule" "ingress_dms_silver_aurora" {
  count = var.rds_aurora_postgres_enabled ? 1 : 0
  description       = "DMS Silver Ingress"
  type              = "ingress"
  from_port         = "5432"
  to_port           = "5432"
  protocol          = "tcp"
  source_security_group_id       = aws_security_group.dms_instance_silver.id
  security_group_id = module.rds_aurora_postgres[count.index].primary_rds_server_security_group_id
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment. That should work when count is 1 or 0?

Comment: Yes, since both the module and the SG are using the same variable which decides if they will be created or not.